# PostgreSQL: multiple sub-selects to populate a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a denormalized table named `cars_denorm` that has the following columns:

```
id | make | model | color | comment
```

To the end of normalizing this data, I created separate tables for the `make`, `model`, and `color` columns--these three tables consist of an `id` column and a `name` column. For example, the `make` table has rows such as `1 -> honda`, `2 -> mazda`, `3 -> ford`; the `color` table contains rows such as `1 -> black` and `2 -> red`.

I'm trying to populate a `cars_norm` table that was the columns

```
id | make_id | model_id | color_id | comments
```

and that references the ids from the `make`, `model`, and `color` tables. Basically I want to iterate through every row in the `cars_denorm` table, and for every row, query for the respective ids in the `make`, `model`, and `color` tables and insert these ids as a single row in the `cars_norm` table (along with the value from the `comments` column). I've been trying to achieve this with sub-selects and PostgreSQL's `WITH` keyword but can't get it to work. Can this be done with plain SQL? If not, how do I do this with a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO cars_norm 
      SELECT CD.id, 
             MK.make_id, 
             MO.model_id, 
             CO.color_id,
             CD.comment
      FROM cars_denorm  CD
      JOIN make MK
        ON CD.make = MK.name
      JOIN model MO
        ON CD.model = MO.name
      JOIN color CO
        ON CD.color = CO.name
```